# Azure DevOps. Can Environments Be Used in Non Multi-Stage Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

The documentation for Azure DevOps Environments only [has code for multi-stage Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops):

```
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 
      name: 'smarthotel-dev'
      resourceName: myVM
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world
```

Is it possible to define Environments in non multi-stage Pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to define Environments in non multi-stage Pipelines?

Yes. We can define Environments in non multi-stage Pipelines.

We need to define the environment under **deployment job** level. The stage definition is optional.

For example:

```
jobs:
- deployment: DeployWeb
  displayName: deploy Web App
  pool:
     vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
  environment: 
    name: 'smarthotel-dev'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo Hello world
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [jobs.deployment definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment?view=azure-pipelines)